# открепить элемент прижатый к низу экрана при достижении блока при скролле

Tags: css, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть блок с текстом, где расположены 3 ссылки и есть блок с картинкой(сиденья).
Сиденья имеют стили

```
.chairs{
position:fixed;
bottom:0
}
```

они всегда приклеены к низу экрана
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я доходил до блока с ссылками, блок с сиденьями останавливался и было так,как на картинке, а когда скролил обратно наверх он откреплялся и опять был приклеен к низу экрана

структура

```
<body>
 <img class="chairs" src="images/Chairs.png" alt="">
<div class="center"></div>
 <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

сейчас я сделал на js чтото такое, но это работает неплавно и не работает в обратную сторону

```
<script>

       $(function() {
        function chairsmove() {
        let css = {     
            'position':'absolute',     
        'bottom': '0',
        'transition': '1s' }
        $('.chairs').css(css);
    }
    var blockTop = $('.footer').offset().top;
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.on('load scroll', function() {
        var top = $window.scrollTop();
        var height = $window.height();
        if (top + height >= blockTop) {
            chairsmove();
        }
    });

});

    </script>
```

Comment: Вариант с position: sticky; не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            function chairsDontMove() {
                let css = {
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'bottom': '0',
                    'transition': '1s'
                }
                $('.chairs').css(css);
            }

            function chairsmove() {
                let css = {
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'bottom': '0',
                    'transition': '1s'
                }
                $('.chairs').css(css);
            }
            var blockTop = $('.footer').offset().top;
            var $window = $(window);
            $window.on('load scroll', function () {
                var top = $window.scrollTop();
                var height = $window.height();
                if (top + height >= blockTop) {
                    chairsDontMove();
                } else {
                    chairsmove()
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```